# C# MVC return Request.CreateResponse Return list of item And Display in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How do I return a list of an item using return Request.
my code:

```
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    [Route("current")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCurrent(int version)
    {
        ValidateApiVersionAndState(version);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Email = "Something@gmail.com", FirstName = "Some", LastName = "thing", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1990, 9, 6), MontlySalary = "50000.00" });

        //var UserModel = new List<UserDB>();
        //UserModel.Add(new UserDB { Id = 1, Email = "something@gmail.com", FirstName = "Some", LastName = "Thing", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1990, 9, 6), MonthlySalary = 50000.00 });
        //UserModel.Add(new UserDB { Id = 1, Email = "Steve@gmail.com", FirstName = "Steve", LastName = "Wonder", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1984, 8, 4), MonthlySalary = 100000.00 });
        //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { UserModel });

    }
}
```

Comment: create a `new List<object>() { ...your objects here }` and pass that to the response

Comment: what is the parent type of base controller. `ApiController` or `Controller`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `List<object>() { ...your objects here }` and pass that to the response.

```
public class UserController : BaseController {
    [Route("current")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCurrent(int version) {
        ValidateApiVersionAndState(version);
        var result = new List<object>() {
            new { Email = "Something@gmail.com", FirstName = "Some", LastName = "thing", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1990, 9, 6), MontlySalary = "50000.00" },
            new { Email = "Steve@gmail.com", FirstName = "Steve", LastName = "Wonder", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1984, 8, 4), MonthlySalary = 100000.00 }
        );

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: How will i display this in a view. My current view:

Comment: class="container">
    <h2>User</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Date of Birth</th>
                <th>Yearly Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
    </table>
</div>

Comment: <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="txtEmail">{{user?.Email}}</td>
                <td id="txtEmail">{{user?.FirstName}}</td>
                <td id="txtEmail">{{user?.LastName}}</td>
                <td id="txtEmail">{{user?.DateOfBirth | date}}</td>
                <td id="txtEmail">{{user?.MontlySalary}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

Comment: Update your original post with this information. what version of asp.net mvc are you using?